# Is there a way to turn off Steam cloud saves for all Steam games?

Tags: steam, steam-cloud

I hate Steam cloud saves, they are awful. I know how to turn off Steam cloud for each game that supports it individually, but that's a super annoying and very inefficient way to do it. Since Steam cloud is the default setting for any game supporting it, any new games will use Steam Cloud unless I remember to turn it off. I have a hard time remembering when my mom's birthday is or what day it is, so that's not ideal to say the least.

Does anyone know of a global setting in the Steam settings that I am not seeing that would just disable Steam cloud completely?

Comment: Please note that if you disable Steam cloud, you won't be able to save your progress in some games, such as Killing Floor.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! Great Q&A combo!

Comment: Just sincere question, but what's the problem with Steam cloud? Seems to do its job well enough for me (though I game very little).

Comment: @DavidMulder Steam cloud works fine for a single computer for a single account with permanent connectivity to the servers. If you play on multiple devices (say, a computer, a laptop and a SteamOS console) and play the same games on each, there are times when Steam cloud gets confused about which saves are the most recent. This gets even worse when you play certain games offline on one of the machines and want to keep saves separate, because Steam tries to keep saves synchronized and asks which saves you want to keep.

Comment: @Nzall Why would you want to keep saves separate unless you're engaging in (illegal) account sharing? Also, when Steam *does* get confused about the newest saves, you simply get asked which ones you want to use...sure it's a little annoying but that doesn't seem like grounds for *hating* cloud saves...

Comment: @Cronax There are reasons beyond account sharing to keep saves separate. For example, if one of your games has mods or another reason why your saves might be incompatible with another machine, you may want to not sync those saves to avoid the risk of save corruption. Also, if steam gets confused about the newest saves, it doesn't give an option to keep both saves as is. Either you download the cloud saves and lose the local, or you upload the local saves and lose the cloud saves.

Comment: I have had Steam do weird and infuriating stuff with my saves...like wipe them out completely because it got confused. And like Nzall mentioned, I have Skyrim with ENB and tons of mods installed on my main desktop but not on my laptop which cant really run anything but vanilla.

Comment: Besides, I take care of my savegame syncing myself. I use a nifty program called GameSave Manager which automatically locates and backs up your games. If it can't locate the saves, you can manually point it to them. I have it backing my saves up on a nightly basis to my 4TB NAS. I also like to add all the games I own, even if their not installed. That way, if I ever install them again, I'm still covered. Again, my memory isn't the greatest.

Answer (score 12):

Yes there is a way to disable Steam Cloud. To do so, go to Steam Settings->Cloud->Enable Steam Cloud synchronization.

Comment: Disabling this might break some games. I recall that for example Dishonored would crash hard  on start when steam cloud was disabled.

Comment: I've still got a game that saves my player info even after disabling this ad uninstalling the game completely. Is there another alternative than uninstalling Steam completely?